# What is the difference between in and on?

Tags: prepositions, difference

There are two sentences :-

> The children play on the playground.

or

> The children play in the playground.

The second looks better and we can say it is correct because they are playing in the enclosed area of playground but the first one can have the argument that they are playing on the surface not below the surface.

Which one should be correct? Please generalise a rule if you can.

Comment: Both are possible for the reasons you give, but I think _in_ is probably the most common. You can use Google Ngrams to check if you are interested.

Comment: @KateBunting Can you give reason why one is more suitable?

Comment: I didn't say _more suitable_, I said _probably more commonly used_ - because a children's playground is usually a fairly small fenced-off area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately theres no real reason why one would be more suitable than the other. It would really depend on the speaker and its fine to use either. Because a playground is a finite area,(fenced in, has a paved ground designated for it), in or on works in both sentences. They are in the playground area and they are on its grounds.

Comment: I disagree. Only "in" is possible in the OP's example. It would be unnatural to say "The children play on the playground".

Comment: That could be a regional thing? I do hear on almsot as often as I hear in where i live, in regards to stuff like where someone is doing something.